# How to fix html5 video freeze?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have an HTML5 video tag on a home page of a website. But when I check the website on browsers like chrome and firefox, the video is freezing even though it is set to autoplay.

Video tag code:

```
    <div class="video-container fullscreen fixed video-container-overlay hide-on-mobile">
        <video muted="muted" autoplay preload loop>
          <source src="my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="my_video.mp4" type="video/ogg" />
        </video>
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause a video to freeze. Setup a [mcve] for us.

Comment: Could be a server issue (slow network or low-performance server). But in any case, not a programming problem. The code is flawless.